# Can not upload images with php using Jquery form Plugin

Tags: php, jquery, upload, jquery-forms-plugin

I try to upload image/Multiple Images with PHP using Jquery form plugin

**all data successfully insert to database but only images not work**

**this is my first usage to jquery.form.js plugin**

this is my HTML code

```
<form method="POST" action="data/addtrip.php" class="form-horizontal form-groups-bordered">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="panel panel-gradient" data-collapsed="0">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    Trip information
                </div>

                <div class="panel-options">
                    <a href="#" data-rel="collapse"><i class="entypo-down-open"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Trip Name</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="title" placeholder="Trip Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="category" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Category</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category" required>
                                <option></option>
                                <?php foreach($categorys as $cat):?>
                                <option value="<?echo $cat['id'];?>"><?echo $cat['title'];?></option>
                                <?php endforeach;?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="price" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Trip Price</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="price" placeholder="Trip Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="details" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Information</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <textarea class="form-control autogrow" name="details" placeholder="Trip Details"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="images" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Multiple files</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-5">

                            <input type="file" class="form-control file2 inline btn btn-primary" name="images" multiple="multiple" data-label="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up'></i> &nbsp;Browse Files">

                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <button type="submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-lg btn-info submit">Add trip</button>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

and this is my Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').ajaxForm( function(data) {

            var thisform = $(this);



            if($.trim(data) == 'Please check all fields'){
                $('.alert').hide();
                $(thisform).before('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+ data +'<i class="fa fa-2x fa-times pull-left"></i></div>');
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},300);
            } else {
                $('.btn i').hide();
                $('form .btn').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i>');


                setTimeout( function() {

                  $('.alert').hide();
                  $(thisform).before('<div class="alert alert-success">'+ data +'<i class="fa fa-2x fa-check pull-left"></i></div>');
                  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},300);

                }, 1500 );


                setTimeout(function() {
                      location.reload();

                }, 3000 );

            }


        });
    });

});
```

and this is my php code

```
if(isset($_POST)){
  $title    = $_POST['title'];
  $category = $_POST['category'];
  $details  = $_POST['details'];
  $price    = $_POST['price'];
  $date     = date('Y-m-d');

  // Execute database query
  $insert = insert_trip($title, $category, $details, $price, $date);

  if(!empty($_FILES['images']['name'])) {

      $lastid  = last_trip();
    foreach($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
        $file_tmp  =$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type =$_FILES['images']['type'][$key];



          $desired_dir="../../includes/trip_images/";
          if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
              mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);      // Create directory if it does not exist
          }
          $image_name = rand().$file_name;
          move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../../includes/trip_images/".$image_name);
          insert_trip_images($lastid['id'], $image_name);
      }

  }

  if(!empty($insert)) {

    echo 'Your Trip is succesfully add !';

  } else {

    echo 'Please check all fields';

  }

}
```

Comment: Please include your HTML form and jQuery code that handles it. The problem doesn't nessesarily lie within your PHP code. To be able to debug, we need all relevant code (except for the plugin / jQuery library ofcourse).

Comment: Ye, just as I suspected. Try adding the parameter `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form. So `<form method="POST" action="data/addtrip.php" class="form-horizontal form-groups-bordered" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. You can't upload files without it.

Comment: Thank you @icecub, i forget this but it`s still not working!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your form.